# Asterisk is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, grep

After switching from 18.04 to 20.04, I noticed that the asterisk thing doesn't work.

For example: If I want to remove all nvidia packages, I type in `sudo apt remove *nvidia*` and apt removes any package that contains the string `nvidia`. But when I try to do it in 20.04, it doesn't work. Apt says `package not found`. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can type :

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
```

Comment: Thanks! I rarely use ```apt-get``` so I didn't know.